# How to call js document.ready function in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am writing a webgame using jquery document.ready. When I call js function in html, it does not work:

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function init(){blablabla...}
})
```

html:

```
<script src="function.js"></script>
<script>
function bla(){
    if (blablabla)
        init();
}
</script>
```

I learned html and js for only a few weeks. I have no idea why it does not work.

Comment: Remove `$(document).ready` from your `js` file..`init();` is expecting `init` function in the scope of the `window`..

Comment: The function `init()` is **private** to the `ready` handler. To call it from anywhere you need to make it global. Just move the function outside of `ready`

Comment: @OP, you can refer this: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/womawLg5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please Follow Bottom Step:**

There are two versions of jQuery available for downloading: 
    minified and compressed

The jQuery library is a single JavaScript file, and you reference it with the HTML `<script>` tag (notice that the `<script>` tag should be inside the `<head>` section):

Like:

```html
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

You might have noticed that all jQuery methods in our examples, are inside a document ready event:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

       // jQuery methods go here...

    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach to achieve expected result is to set `init` as property of `document`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready([
    function() {
      function init() {
        // do stuff
        alert("blablabla...") 
      }
      // set `init` as property of `document`
      this.init = init;
    },
    function bla() {
      if ($.isReady /* blablabla */)
        document.init();
    }
  ])
</script>
<body></body>
```